# python3 ModuleNotFoundError for mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am on MacOS 11.6 and having trouble installing the `mysql` package for python3.  Other python packages are working fine.

`which python3` returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3` and `python3 --version` returns `Python 3.10.5`.

I run the command `python3 -m pip install mysql`.

Running `python3 -m pip list` verifies the following packages are installed:

```
mysql              0.0.3
mysqlclient        2.1.1
```

Next I run `python3` and execute at the prompt:

```
>>> import mysql
```

and get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'`

When I change to directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages` and do an `ls` I see:

```
mysql-0.0.3.dist-info/
mysqlclient-2.1.1-py3.10.egg-info/
```

but there is no `mysql-0.0.3` directory.  Only the dist-info and egg-info directories are there.

Why isn't the package installing correctly?  I've scoured all of the related posts but nothing I've found has solved my particular problem.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install official mysql connector package.

`$ pip install mysql-connector-python`

For details:

[MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/)

[Manual download and install from archives](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-python/), select your OS while downloading.

[Manual download and install, latest version](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

After installation:

```
from mysql import connector
connect = connector.connect(host='localhost', user='DB_USER', password='DB_PASSWORD', database='DB_NAME')
cursor = connect.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute('SHOW TABLES')
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### mysql is a ghost package.

My sql on pypi’s only purpose is to install other packages in it’s requirements that is why it is a ghost package.
So you’ll have to find the actual package you want to use that was installed via `pip install mysql`

Comment: Where would the actual package be, if not in site-packages?

Comment: It would be there just not called mysql @skrilmps